# marmap package get.NOAA.bathy

Tags: r, package

I have a problem with get.depth. I am using R 3.1.1 on W7 with marmap 0.8.
The examples and other scripts that I have found on SO work fine but the following gives errors or strange output.

```
library(marmap)
search()
gombathy<-getNOAA.bathy(-98, -79, 18,32)
glat<-seq(27,29,1)
glon<-rep(-93,length(glat))
data.frame(glon,glat)
get.depth(gombathy, x=glon, y=glat, locator=FALSE)
glat<-seq(27,30,1)
glon<-rep(-93,length(glat))
data.frame(glon,glat)
get.depth(gombathy, x=glon, y=glat, locator=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:marmap"    "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"
 [8] "package:stringr"   "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
Querying NOAA database ...  
This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size  
Building bathy matrix ...  
  glon glat  
1  -93   27  
2  -93   28  
3  -93   29  
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Depth", value = c(-1323L, -1284L,  :  
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 3  
  glon glat  
1  -93   27  
2  -93   28  
3  -93   29  
4  -93   30  
  Lon Lat Depth.1 Depth.2 Depth.3 Depth.4  
1 -93  27   -1323    -129     -23       3  
2 -93  28   -1284    -128     -23       2  
3 -93  29   -1416    -104     -23       2  
4 -93  30   -1259    -103     -24       0
```

A few hours later:

After seeing Eric's post on Githup, I added .00001 to each of the lat lons and the program operated as expected.

> ```
> get.depth(gombathy, x=glon, y=glat, locator=FALSE)  
>     Lon      Lat Depth
> ```
>
> 1 -92.99999 27.00001 -1259
>   2 -92.99999 28.00001  -103
>   3 -92.99999 29.00001   -24

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot: you found a bug! It is due to the fact that `get.depth()` returns the depth of the cell of the `bathy` object that is the closest to the point for which the depth is requested. In your examples, the points fall right in the middle of four cells of `gombathy`, which was responsible for the strange behavior.

Altering slightly the coordinates of your points leads to the expected behavior for `get.depth()`:

```
glat<-seq(27.1,29.1,1)
glon<-rep(-93.1,length(glat))
```

I updated the code to correct the bug. You can install the new version from github right now or wait for the new version of marmap to be released on CRAN.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("marmap","ericpante")
```